# Reality of speed and time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, speed

I have a very simple question. How does a faster object takes less time for the same distance? A car with a speed of 100km per hour takes one hour to travel 100km while a car with the speed of 50km per hour takes two hours to travel 100km. For the same distance the first car takes half the time of the second car. This means the time pass half the slower car, how?
According to special relativity the time dilation is relative to speed of light and can be  ignored for low speed such as 100 km per hour.

Comment: The situation, that a fast car takes less time for a given distance has nothing to do  with the so called time dilatation. If you drive with 100km/h or only 50km/h you age 1 hour  every hour. When you travel near light speed  say 0,8c you need less of your lifetime to travel to a distant star, as when your speed is half  so 0,4c.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Isn't this obvious that a faster object travels say 1 km earlier than a slower object if both start from 0? If you think that's incorrect you should watch a car race from your TV.

Answer (score 3):

the *rate* at which time passes is the same in both cars. the total *duration* of time spent traveling is twice as long for the slower car.

Comment: Thanks for comments. My question is that how time shrinks for faster car? How faster car experience less time while clocks tick at the same rate.do faster particles experience  less time? If yes the faster  going man should become less old .